# Import function to plugin JS file?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to import my exported js function inside my plugin javascript file and it is not working, getting an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

In my custom plugin file, called social.js, i try to do this:

```
import { facebookRender } from './icons/social/facebookRender';
```

and I export function like this:

```
const facebookRender = function() {
    return (
        // do something
    )
};

export {
    facebookRender
}
```

I am guessing I need to put `type="module"` on script somehow, but don't know where. I enqueue script here:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
        'block',
        plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'social-block.js',
        array('wp-blocks', 'wp-editor'),
        BLOCKS_VERSION
    );
```

Any advice?

Comment: What browser? https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import

Comment: @ceejayoz chrome, it is supported, should work